# Merging two list with certain condition

Tags: python, list

I have `listA = [2,0,0,5,6,0]` and `listB = [4,5,7,3,2,1]`. I want to merge these two list and get `listC = [2,5,7,5,6,1]`. So basically just copy `listA` but if an element in `listA` is zero, replace that element with element from `listB`

I tried using `for` and `if` loop but had no luck:

```
listC = []
for i in listA and listB:
    if listA[i] == 0: 
        listC.append(listB[i])
    else:
        listC.append(listA[i])
```

I am new to python, so some explanation with solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to loop over the indices, not the elements of the list.
So what we need here is `for i in range(len(listA))`.
We can break this expression further to get a better understanding:

- `len(listA)` gives the number of elements in list A. Clearly, this solution will only work if `listA` and `listB` have the same number of elements. In your example, `len(listA)` equals 5
- `range(len(listA))` will iterate over a *range* of integers: from `0` to `len(listA) - 1`. For our running example, this will be `range(5)`, so from `0` to `4`
- `for i in range(len(listA))` then just loops over `i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

```py
listA = [2,0,0,5,6,0]
listB = [4,5,7,3,2,1]
listC = []

for i in range(len(listA)):
    if listA[i] == 0:
        listC.append(listB[i])
    else:
        listC.append(listA[i])

print(listC) # [2, 5, 7, 5, 6, 1]
```

---

I'll leave a couple of one-liners you can come back to once you are farther ahead in your python journey.

- `listC = [b if a == 0 else a for (a, b) in zip(listA, listB)]`
- `list(map(lambda ab: ab[1] if ab[0] == 0 else ab[0], zip(listA, listB)))`

Good luck!

Comment: That explanation helps a ton! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*(Because you say new in python, I send for you another approach maybe helps you.)*

You can use `enumerate`. With `enumerate` you can iterate over `index` and `value` in `listA` and when value of `listA == 0` you can with `index` go to `listB` and get `value` in `listB` and insert value in `listA`.

```
listA = [2,0,0,5,6,0] 
listB = [4,5,7,3,2,1]

for index, value in enumerate(listA):
    if listA[index] == 0:
        listA[index] = listB[index]
        
print(listA)
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 7, 5, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are iterating over the elements of `listB` rather than the indexes, so when you you are indexing the lists you are not pulling the right values. There are two options here.

The simplest is to simply iterate over the indexes rather than the elements:

```py
for i in range(len(listA)):
    if listA[i] == 0: 
        listC.append(listB[i])
    else:
        listC.append(listA[i])
```

If you can assume both lists will always been of the same length you can leverage [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over the elements of both lists at the same time:

```py
for a, b in zip(istA, listb):
    if a == 0:
        listC.append(b)
    else:
        listC.append(a)
```

or more simply as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
[b if a == 0 else a for a, b in zip(listA, listB)]
```